# sending information to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-books

I found a barcode scanner project on git hub that I incorporated into my app [link](https://github.com/hyperoslo/BarcodeScanner). I am using google books API to get information on the books I scanned.

```
func getBookInfo(isbn: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn13:\(isbn)") else {
        print("the url is not valid")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(response)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no error but no data")
            print(response)
            return
        }
        guard let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else {
            print("the JSON is not valid")
            return
        }
        if let arrayOfTitles = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.title") as? [String] {
            self.BookName.text = "\(arrayOfTitles[0])"
            print(self.BookName.text!)
        }
        if let arrayOfAuthors = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.authors") as? [[String]] {
             self.Author.text =  "\((arrayOfAuthors[0])[0])"
            print(self.Author.text!)
        }
        if let arrayOfCategories = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.categories") as? [[String]] {
            self.Category.text =  "\((arrayOfCategories[0])[0])"
            print(self.Category.text!)
        }
        if let arrayOfISBN13 = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier") as? [[String]] {
            self.ISBN13.text =  "\((arrayOfISBN13[0])[0])"
            print(self.ISBN13.text!)
        }
        if let arrayOfISBN10 = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier") as? [[String]] {
            self.ISBN10.text =  "\((arrayOfISBN10[0])[1])"
            print(self.ISBN10.text!)
        }
        if let arrayOfFormat = (jsonResult as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "items.volumeInfo.printType") as? [String] {
            self.CoverType.text =  "\(arrayOfFormat[0])"
            print(self.CoverType.text!)
        }

    }).resume()
}
```

After I scan the books and have received the information, I would like to dismiss the view controller that has the barcode scanner and in the view controller that appears, I would like to display the information of the book I just scanned.

```
extension MultipleImageViewController: BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate {

    func barcodeScanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String) {


        if code.isEmpty {

            let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
                controller.resetWithError()

            }

        }
        else{

            getBookInfo(isbn: code)


            let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, when the barcode scanner view controller is dismissed, I have to exit the app and then come back to the app in order for my information to show in the view controller that I want it to. Without leaving the app and coming back the information that I received from the barcode scanner does not display in the desired view controller.

Comment: What do you mean by this " I have to exit the app and then come back to the app in order for my information to show in the view controller that I want it to. "

Comment: Will you please elaborate what piece of code is not working in expected way?

Comment: When I scan the book code and the book is found, I would like to dismiss the barcode controller and then have my found information displayed on the existing view controller but it does not display unless I press the home button to exit the app and then press the app again. Then the information is displayed

Comment: I think you forgot to update the UI for received information after dismissing the controller.

Comment: @Shubham how would I do that?

Comment: Before dismissing the view controller just update the UI with you book data you received like you were doing in viewDidLoad(I guess) method. It is better to make a separate method for this.

Comment: you can use protocol method

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is not updating because the method `viewDidLoad` does not get called when that view controller is returned to since it already loaded. Instead, create a delegate for the parent that will get called when you dismiss the child view controller. Sort of like this:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, BarcodeDelegate {
    func presentChildViewController() {
        let childViewController = ChildViewController()
        childViewController.delegate = self
        present(childViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func dismissedChildViewController(code: String) {
       // update UI
    }
}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: BarcodeDelegate?

    func dismiss() {
        delegate.dismissedChildViewController(code: getCode())
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

protocol BarcodeDelegate {
    func dismissedChildViewController(code: String)
}
```

It is difficult to really understand what the problem is, so this may or may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you are right, I am just having the hardest time applying it to my code. I tried calling the `barcodeScanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String)` delegate in viewdidload but I get errors in the parameters

Comment: @juelizabeth, viewDidLoad does not get called when you return from another morally presented vc. The parent is the delegate of the child, so the child calls delegate’s method once it’s done.